# Can we make either of the serializer fields compulsory in the serializer class itself?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer class, which I want to primarily use to fetch request data and use it to save details in different models. I want to have in request body either one or both the parameters. I can handle it in my `views.py`, though I want to know is there a way we can have that either or both check inside the serializer class itself?

Thanks in advance :)

```
#serializers.py

class ScanUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    assets = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField())
    issues = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make either of the two fields compulsory, you could use the validate method to check and enforce it.

E.g.

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class ScanUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    assets = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField())
    issues = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField())
    

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if not ("assets" in self.initial_data or "issues" in self.initial_data):
            raise ValidationError("Either assets or issues need to be set.")
        return attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you want to do, but it seems the case for overwriting the methods `def create(self, validated_data)` and/or `def update(self, instance, validated_data)`

You can consult the documentation here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances